# Close a sliding div by clicking outside of it

Tags: menu, slide

I spent hours to find a solution to my problem, but nothing worked yet :/

I made [this pen](http://codepen.io/dragoeco/pen/LkQPvk) which is working fine. It's a basic sliding menu with a open/close button (based on this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kiki_Dee/4UTQk/)) but I like to add a feature which allow users to close the menu by clicking anywhere outside of it.

Here is the code:

HTML

```
<div class='header'>
  <span class='button'>&#9776;</span>
  <span class="logo">LOGO HERE</span>
</div>
<div class='side-panel'>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#'>ITEM 1</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>ITEM 2</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>ITEM 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class='content'>CONTENT HERE</div>
```

JS

```
$('.button').click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('active')){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
      $(this).html("&#9776;");
    $('.side-panel').animate({
    right:"-220px"
    });
    $(this).animate({
    right:"0"
    });
  }
  else{
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).html("&#9587;");
    $('.side-panel').animate({
    right:"0",
  });
  $('.button').animate({
    right:"220px"
  });
  }
});
```

I found some very interesting topic here and I tried to add this :

```
$(document).click(function(){
  if ($('.button').hasClass('active')){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

but doesn't worked. My knowledge with Js is basic (as my english (sorry)), and I'm pretty sure I'm not far from the solution but I spent already more than 3 hours and I'm starting to desperate ;) I hope I was clear enough but if you need more details, feel free to ask. Cheers, and thanks for your help.

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/dragoeco/pen/LkQPvk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## quick and dirty:

act as if the button is pressed when you click on content:

```
$('.content').click(
    function() { 
      $(".button").click(); 
    });
```

## better:

extract the code from .button click event in a function and call that twice:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
  showhide();
});

$('.content').click(function() { 
  showhide();
});

function showhide()
{
  var $this = $(".button");
  if($this.hasClass('active')){
  $this.removeClass('active');
    $this.html("&#9776;");
  $('.side-panel').animate({
    right:"-220px"
  });
  $this.animate({
    right:"0"
  });
  }
  else{
  $this.addClass('active');
  $this.html("&#9587;");
  $('.side-panel').animate({
    right:"0",
  });
  $('.button').animate({
    right:"220px"
  });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jack for the time you took to answer me. Both solution works but the problem is that any click in the page opens the menu now. I spent 2 more hours with my problem and finally found a solution which is working fine :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution. I just added this :

```
$('.content').click(function() {
  if($('.button').hasClass('active')){
   $('.button').removeClass('active');
   $('.button').html("&#9776;");
   $('.side-panel').animate({
    right:"-220px"
  });
  $('.button').animate({
    right:"0"
  });
  } 
});
```

Now, any click in the content closes the div .side-panel